# SQL UPDATE SET a column to be equal to a certain value in a related table that referenced by a different column?

Tags: mysql, sql

There is a table of customers and table of call_card.
 card_id is the foreign key in customers table that reference call_card table

[image: customers table]

**The image above is the table of customers**

[image]

**The image above is call_card table**

what i want is
(if location_id and visit_id in customers table is equal to location_id and visit_id in call_card then i should set card_id in customers table to be equal with card_id in call_card).

What is the best approach to this scenario,
I apologize for not being word-perfect in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like a `join` and `update`:

```
update customers c join
       call_card cc
       on c.location_id = cc.location_id and c.visit_id = cc.visit_id
    set c.card_id = cc.card_id;
```